# Issue in autocomplete service method

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written below lines of code

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static List<string> GetNames(string prefixText)
{
    OrganisationManger OrgManager = new OrganisationManger();
    Table<Organisation> ResultSet = OrgManager.GetOrganisationWithSameName(prefixText);
    List<string> Names = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < ResultSet.Count; i++)
    {
        Names.Add(ResultSet.Rows[i][1].ToString());
    }
    return Names;
}
```

It's not working in this line `ResultSet.Rows[i][1].ToString()`. Can anyone tell me how to **grab** Name in the iteration of ResultSet.

Actually I am trying to grab list of names in Autocomplete textbox...

Comment: Can you define `not working`? Are you getting an error? If yes then what?

Comment: Whenever i see indexes and for loop I do see also IndexOutOfRange Exception. We need more info about what does it mean that its 'not working'

Comment: Error 1958 'DataModals.Table<DataModals.Organisation>' does not contain a definition for 'Rows' and no extension method 'Rows' accepting a first argument of type 'DataModals.Table<DataModals.Organisation>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) E:\TFS\1FourCommunity\14Muslims.Web\14Muslims.Web\REGISTRATION\RegOrganisationEdit.aspx.cs 1067 33 14Muslims.Web